# Simplify specific XPath expression

Tags: xpath

I would like to know if the following XPath expression can be simplified:

```
//map[requester/@type='2' and requester/code]
```

Some test data:

```
<root>
    <map>
        <requester type="2">
            <code>a</code>
            <code>b</code>
        </requester>
    </map>

    ...
</root>
```

My objective is to get only map elements which have at least one requester with type attribute and value '2' and also have at least one code element.

Comment: Without seeing the data you are running it against, that isn't really possible to answer.

Comment: I have added the test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, this is probably as simple as it could be.  However, it doesn't match what you are describing doing.

Here you are selecting *map* elements where

1. There is a *requester* element with *type* attribute equal to 2
2. There is a *requester* element with a *code* element
3. The requester elements in (1) and (2) are **not necessarily** the same

For example, the *map* element in the following is selected:

```
<root>
    <map>
        <requester type="2"/>
        <requester>
            <code>a</code>
        </requester>
    </map>
</root>
```

If you want the elements in (1) and (2) to be the same, you should use (simplified slightly at the suggestion of kjhughes)

```
//map[requester[@type='2']/code]
```

Here we select all map elements which have a requester element which in turn has an attribute *type* with a value of 2 and a *code* element.

Comment: Great improvement! Thank you!

Comment: Nice explanation (+1).  Here's a variation that shaves a few chars off the length:  `//map[requester[@type='2']/code]`

Comment: Assuming that I want also 'codes' that have non-whitespace would a solution like: //map[requester[@type='2']/code[normalize-space()]] could be nice?

Comment: @kjhughes You are right, that is a little better.  I should have thought of that improvement.  I have edited this into the answer.

Comment: @EfstathiosChatzikyriakidis Yes, that modification will give you only map elements which contain requester elements with a type attribute of 2 which in turn contain AT LEAST ONE code element which does not consist entirely of whitespace.

Comment: This is great. Thanks.